# How to debug this search & replace strings snippet?

Tags: php, filters, the-content

I add this code (modify from [this comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/#comment-5125)) into my plugin:

```php
function wpdocs_replace_content( $text_content ) {
    if ( is_page() ) {
        $text = array(
            'chamber' => '<strong>chamber</strong>',
        );
        $text_content = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $text_content );
    }
    return $text_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpdocs_replace_content' );
```

But it doesn't work. What can I do to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Notice the `if ( is_page()`  line. It's to indicate that the snippet only works with pages, not posts. Pull it out of the if condition if you want to apply it site-wide.

```php
function wpdocs_replace_content( $text_content ) {
    $text = array(
        'chamber' => '<strong>chamber</strong>',
    );
    $text_content = str_ireplace( array_keys( $text ), $text, $text_content );
    return $text_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpdocs_replace_content' );
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution to this! Beware that this will replace all occurences of `chamber`, so even `chamberlain` or `<div class="chamber">`. To avoid this, [you can parse the DOM in `$text_content`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and only replace the string in actual content. If the search string is unique enough, this might not be necessary

Answer (score 1):

To debug the aforesaid issue you might need to keep these things in mind.

- Review your function `add_filter('the_content', 'wpdocs_replace_content' );`
- It's filtering the output returned by `the_content()` wordpress function. Which is working quite fine.
- Possible Questions arise that why is this not working in your theme. So the answer to that is your theme is not calling the content via `the_content()` function.
- Check in your template if there is this function called to display your content `echo get_the_content();` Just change it to `the_content()`

Thanks & Keep posted